# Return variable from function in php from mySQL Array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, global

I have a function in functions.php as follows:

```
function verticals($dbc, $vertical){
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM verticals WHERE verticalTitle='$vertical' ");
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
return $title = $rows['verticalTitle'];
}
}
```

I have a php page that I would like to be able to use the $title variable for display:

```
<?php
    verticals($dbc,$vertical);
?>
    <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
```

If I conduct it this way, I receive the following error: **Notice: Undefined variable: title**.  I have tested the output via an echo statement within the function to ensure that it is returning the correct data.

It is important to me that I am able to assign variables to the results of the rows so that I am able to use them wherever I want in the page.  Also I do not want to use GLOBAL.

Thoughts?

**EDIT 1** Returns *Undefined variable: rows*

functions.php:

```
function verticals($dbc, $vertical){
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM verticals WHERE verticalTitle='$vertical' ");
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
return $rows['verticalTitle'];
}
```

verticals.php:

```
<?php
verticals($dbc,$vertical);
?>
<h2><?php echo $rows['verticalTitle']; ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:** You should not return value from a while loop. You should return an array and loop through this array for echo output.

Try something like this:

```
function verticals($dbc, $vertical){
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM verticals WHERE verticalTitle='$vertical' ");
    $title = array();
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         $title[] = $rows['verticalTitle'];
    }
    return $title;
}
```

**Second:** You called a function butyou did not get return value of this function in any variable.

verticals.php:

```
  <?php
    $title = verticals($dbc,$vertical);
    foreach($title as $rows){
            echo "<h2>". $rows."</h2>";
      } 
    ?>
```

Comment: @6paq : Did you try this?

Comment: This approach results in output of Warning: Illegal string offset 'verticalTitle' and also the letter a in lower case (this makes a little bit of sense as the vertical name in the mysql db is agriculture)

Comment: @6paq: can you print_r($rows); in the for each loop and let me show what you have got?

Comment: I added that and see the result:
agriculture

So we know that it is outputting the data as the $rows variable but not if we put a selector in of that field specifically.

Comment: just give me that result

Comment: agriculture

Warning: Illegal string offset 'verticalTitle' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/employee/verticals.php on line 15

a

Comment: Can you print_r($rows); in verticals function  just above the line  $title[] = $rows['verticalTitle'];  and tell me what is in the $rows there?

Comment: Array ( [0] => 1 [idverticals] => 1 [1] => agriculture [verticalTitle] => agriculture [2] => testdata1 [definition] => testdata1 [3] => testdata2 [qualifiedExamples] => testdata2 [4] => testcontactdata3 [verticalContacts] => testcontactdata3 [5] => testdata4 [howQualify] => testdata4 [6] => testdata5 [supportingDocs] => testdata5 [7] => testdata6 [helpfulLinks] => testdata6 )

Comment: @6paq: I have updated my answer. Can you try it now?

Comment: That works perfectly for the single instance - for retrieving more than one variable from the function would I simply `$description = array();` and then create another while loop?

Comment: If you return more than one verticalTitle from your function then my current code will be work.

Comment: fantastic thank you - I would up vote you if I could!

Answer (score 0):

why are you saying

```
return $title = $rows['verticalTitle'];
```

you should just have

```
return $rows['verticalTitle'];
```

If you want the variable $title to have the info at the end use

```
$title = verticals($dbc,$vertical);
```

when you call the functions.

lastly, in order to get the value by column name like you are, $rows['verticalTitle'], you need to use mysqli_fetch_assoc, like this:

```
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

a word of warning though, this will only return one value. Are you trying to get more?

Comment: I have tried it that way and received a **Undefined variable: rows**

Comment: Yes eventually I want to have multiple values but obviously I need to start with the first one.

`function verticals($dbc, $vertical){

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM verticals WHERE verticalTitle='$vertical' ");

    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    return $rows['verticalTitle'];
    }`

Comment: you need mysqli_fetch_assoc to get an associative array. I always forget to check that but everyone has problems with it. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. 
First because the "while" it seems the functions is returning several values, but it only returns one. You don't need a "while" at all.
Second $title variable is undefined because you have called the function and not attibuted it's result to a variable.
I've corrected the code to a functional level:

http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/hsp-6w6

Hope it helps.